# How to split string by two or more word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string

```
"@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2' and @bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ != 'test1' or @wersf4vrdf1f5e@ == 'test2' and @sdfsd56fe6sdfs@ != 'test1'"
```

I need to separate them by `and` and `or`.
I want output like this

```
@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2'
@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ != 'test1'
@wersf4vrdf1f5e@ == 'test2'
@sdfsd56fe6sdfs@ != 'test1'
```

I can split by only one work like `and` or `or`. But I need to split if it has `and` or it has `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex with OR (`|`)

```js
var str = "@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2' and @bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ != 'test1' or @wersf4vrdf1f5e@ == 'test2' and @sdfsd56fe6sdfs@ != 'test1'"

var strArr = str.split(/ and | or /g);
console.log(strArr);
```

**Updated as you stated another case in comment** by splitting with the words which are not inside the single quotes:

```js
var str = "@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2' and @bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ != 'test1' or @wersf4vrdf1f5e@ == 'test2' and @sdfsd56fe6sdfs@ != 'test1' and @bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2 and or other value'"

var strArr = str.split(/(?!\B'[^']*) and (?![^']*'\B)|(?!\B'[^']*) or (?![^']*'\B)/g);
console.log(strArr);
```

Comment: Great. I have one more case: consider `@bm5ja7qyd1ljuqcqb09@ == 'test2 and or other value'`. It split the text in single quote but I need that It keep string as usual.